# Determining size of data[0] in AVFrame of FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, sizeof, memcpy

I am trying to allocate AVFrame->data[0] of a video frame to uint8_t* buffer using the following lines of code :

```
size_t sizeOfFrameData = mpAVFrameInput->linesize[0] * mpAVFrameInput->height;
        
memcpy(mFrameData, mpAVFrameInput->data[0], sizeOfFrameData);
```

I would like to know if this is a correct way of copying frame data to uint8_t* variable in FFMPEG?

Comment: Did you try if it works (i.e. compiles and you get expected output)?

Comment: Although the program is being compiled but not getting expected output

Comment: Then most likely this is not the correct way (supposed there are not other bugs in your code).

Comment: That is correct for non-planar formats. For planar formats (like YUV) you need to do the same for the other planes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the buffer size:

```
int avpicture_get_size(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height);
```

To copy pixel data:

```
int avpicture_layout(const AVPicture *src, enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
                     int width, int height,
                     unsigned char *dest, int dest_size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `avpicture_get_size()` is deprecated , this is possible with:

```
int numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(
    enum AVPixelFormat
    int width,
    int height,
    int align
    );
```

note that for align value of 32 is usually used , I have seen posts using 1 bit might cause distortion on the frame;

Its possible however to fill frame buffer data (i.e without size information) with :

```
int av_image_fill_arrays(uint8_t *dst_data[4], int dst_linesize[4],
                         const uint8_t *src,
                         enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height, int align);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `avpicture_*` API is now deprecated. Instead, use `av_image_fill_plane_sizes` to get each plane's size (the size of data[0] array).

```
int av_image_fill_plane_sizes   (
size_t  size[4],
enum AVPixelFormat  pix_fmt,
int     height,
const ptrdiff_t     linesizes[4] 
)
```

Note that the `linesizes` should be converted to `ptrdiff_t (long long*)` first.

You can find more here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__picture.html